# Angular ng-options make specific option first in list

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

```
<select ng-model="person" 
        ng-options="item.name for item in persons track by item.id">
        <option value="">-- select --</option>
</select>



 persons = 
{
    1: 'Ted',
    2: 'Ben',
    3: 'Anna',
    4: 'Micky',
    5: 'Ricky' 
}



   It looks like:
-- select --
Ted
Ben
Anna
Micky
Ricky
```

By default option is -- select --. List reading from db.  Is there a way, to make option with value 4 first in list, but after -- select --  and make it the next:

```
 -- select --
    **Micky**
    Ted    
    Ben
    Anna
    Ricky
```

Comment: please post valid thing,you are referring persons in ng-options whereas there is nowhere I see persons reference.

Comment: The only way to change the order of the select would be to change the order of the list; i.e. change the value you are tracking by;  in this case, you would have to have the element you want to be first in the list have the lowest `item.id`, or create a new column to define the order, and assign the order value / track by to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add an orderBy filter to your list of data in ng-options.

Update your HTML template to this:

```
<select ng-model="person" 
        ng-options="item.name for item in persons|orderBy:sortOptions track by item.id">
        <option value="">-- select --</option>
</select>
```

And define the orderBy predicate in your controller:

```
$scope.sortOptions = function(option) {
  if (option.name === 'Micky') {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```